# Why I'm getting error: invalid operands to binary expression after overloaded += operand?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the `+=` operator for a simple mathematical `Vector` class, to sum the elements of two vectors, like this:

```cpp
vector1 += vector2
```

Part of `Vector2D.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _VECTOR2D_H_
#define _VECTOR2D_H_

class Vector2D
{
public:

    Vector2D():x(0),y(0){}
    ~Vector2D(){}

    /* All the mathematical operation ... */

    // Overloading operators
    Vector2D& operator+=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator*=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator/=(const Vector2D& rhs);
    Vector2D& operator-=(const Vector2D& rhs);

private:

    double x;
    double y;
};
```

Then part of `Vector2D.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "Vector2D.h"

Vector2D& Vector2D::operator+=(const Vector2D& rhs)
{
    x += rhs.x;
    y += rhs.y;
    return *this;
}
```

Now, in the `.cpp` class, I want to use the operator:

```cpp
void MovingObject::move()
{
    m_pVelocity += m_pAcceleration;
    m_pVelocity->limit(m_fMax_speed);
    m_pPosition += m_pVelocity();
    m_pAcceleration->zero();
}
```

The variables `m_pVelocity`, `m_pAcceleration` and `m_pPosition` are all `Vector2D*` pointers.

When I try to compile, this is what I get from the compiler:

[image: compiler's result]

Why does this happen? I've read a lot of papers, and I've seen a lot of examples, and all of them work, but mine does not.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're calling `+=` on pointers instead of the objects they point to.

Comment: A `Vector2D*` ≠ `Vector2D`.  (Why would they be pointer member variables in the MovingObject in the first place?)

Comment: `~Vector2D(){}` -- Off-topic, but do not write empty destructors with no implementation.  Either remove it, or declare it as `=default`.  I know you may have seen other code samples that may do this empty destructor stuff, but this is deemed a code smell since C++11.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_VECTOR2D_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Just to show you the implications of that empty destructor, [look at this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83c14889440d4a33).  Just the change of removing the empty destructor changes the traits of the class.  That may be a crucial thing when it comes to the compiler (or other templated code) working with the class.

Comment: Why are you using `Vector2D` pointers? Is there polymorphism involved or are they pointing at objects owned "elsewhere"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie oh thanks! Yes the book I'm reading use some of them empty. Ok I'll change that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I'll have to change they.

Comment: @CosimoDavideViggiano The books are probably old -- but to their defense, a lot of C++ programmers get into this (bad) habit and just write empty destructors, almost by rote.  Worse yet, many automatic C++ class/code generators that the programmer has no control over produce destructors that are empty in the classes they generate.  In any event, write a destructor when there is something that you actually must do on object destruction.

Comment: A generalization of Paul McKenzie's point is covered in [the Rule of Zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Make sure you are familiar with the Rules of Three and Five as well. It's hard to write effective and efficient C++ without understanding Three/Five/Zero.

Comment: More information about Pete Becker's point: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). Misusing an underscore doesn't bite that often, but when it does, things get weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like on this line you have two pointers

```
m_pVelocity += m_pAcceleration;
```

so you'd need to dereference them to use this operator

```
*m_pVelocity += *m_pAcceleration;
```

Comment: Damn! That worked like a charm! Shame on me, I forgot this!!

Thanks to everyone for the comments and helping me to improve. And you are right, I'll change from pointers to reference, no need to be pointers at least not these.